# how to validate a string entry on Editext within the click of a button

Tags: android

I have an application and noticed that I didn't include validation for a string entry. When the user clicks a button I want the  button which is an onclick method to check if the entry within an editText is a string or an integer.

Overall I want to be able to only allow strings to pass through from an editText not integers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways how to do that. One of them is to match the regular expression:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);          
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        if(str.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            // no integers allowed - no further processing
            return;
        }                                   
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you  very much works great, I understand the str.matches("[0-9]") which checks if the numbers are between 0 and 9 but what does the * (asterix) do. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. "[0-9]" matches a single digit. "*" is a quantifier that matches any number of preceding symbol (this means empty string is also matched here). If you want to match at least one digit use "+" quantifier. For more info search for "regular expressions". In java see here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum